# Fortran read in input file string

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran, so forgive my ignorance but I need help understanding something.

```
   Smith   Bess   E091099085
   Roberts Ricky  T079 83088
```

Where 'Smith' and 'Roberts' are the surnames and 'Bess' and 'Ricky' are the first names. I seem to do fine reading the file in. I can get the three columns as it would appear in the text file. My question to you all is if there is a way where I can read in 'E091099085' and 'T079 83088' (as is) and have the values be separated in some way. I would also like to add up those values for some kind of total. I would like to read in the last string as one letter and three separate numbers, instead of one long string. Is there a way to truncate it or something? Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you say "three separate numbers", how do you interpret the `T079 83088`, as 79, 83, and 88, or as 79, 830, and 88? Also, are these values always at the same location in each line?

Answer (score 0):

If, as the two lines suggest, the data is stored in a fixed format, as in: Every line has

- 8 Characters for the Surname, immediately followed by
- 7 Characters for the Firstname, immediately followed by
- A single character for some letter, immediately followed by
- 3 3-digit integers, end-to-end

then you're in luck: That is the easiest way to read the data in Fortran, you just need to describe the format:

```
read(*, '(A8, A7, A1, 3I3)') surname, firstname, letter, val1, val2, val3
```

should do the trick.